# Assignment operator and copy constructor for class containing base class pointer to derived templated class

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, deep-copy, assignment-operator

Apologies for the long title. I am trying to write an assignment operator and a copy constructor for a class which I call `Store`.

The purpose of `Store` is hold other structures (e.g. integers, floats), identified by a `std::string`, which can be added/retrieved from the `Store`. This is implemented with a `std::map`, with a `std::string` as the 'key' in the map and the particular structure as the 'value' in the map.

`Store` is defined as follows:

```
    class Store {

    public:

      Store() {}

      template <class T>
      const T& get(const std::string& key) const;

      template <class T>
      void put(const std::string& key, const T& value, const bool& overwrite = false);

    private:

      std::map<std::string,FieldBase*> m_data;

    };
```

where `FieldBase` is defined as follows:

```
    class FieldBase {

    public:

      FieldBase() {}
      virtual ~FieldBase() {}

    }
```

and a class derived from `FieldBase` called `Field` is defined as follows:

```
    template <class T>
    class Field : public FieldBase {

    public:

      Field(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

      template <class U>
      Field(const Field<U>& other) : m_value( U(other.m_value) ) {}

      template <class U>
      Field& operator=(const Field<U>& other) 
      { 
        m_value = U(other.m_value);
        return *this;
      }

      virtual ~Field() {}

      const T& get() const { return m_value ; }

     private:

       T m_value;

    };
```

The functionality in `Store` to add and retrieve, is defined below.
To retrieve, one uses `Store::get()` :

```
    template <class T>
    const T& Store::get(const std::string& key) const
    {

      std::map<std::string,FieldBase*>::const_iterator it = m_data.find(key);

      if ( it == m_data.end() ) {
        std::cout << "Field with name " << key <<" doesn't exist!" << std::endl;
        throw 0;
      }

      Field<T>* field = dynamic_cast<Field<T>*>(it->second);
      if ( field == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Field with name " << key << " doesn't have correct type!" << std::endl;
        throw 0;
      }

      return field->get();

    }
```

and to add, one uses `Store::put()`

```
    template <class T>
    void Store::put(const std::string& key, const T& value, const bool& overwrite)
    {

      std::map<std::string,FieldBase*>::iterator it = m_data.find(key);

      if ( it != m_data.end() ) {
        if ( ! overwrite ) {
          std::cout << "Field with name " << key << " doesn't exist!" << std::endl;
          throw 0;
        }
        else {
          delete it->second;
          it->second = 0;
        }
      }

      Field<T>* field = new Field<T>(value);
      m_data[key] = field;

    }
```

So, having described the classes and their interactions, I finally arrive at the question:

How should the copy constructor and assignment operator look for `Store`?

Obviously, one should iterate over the `std::map<std::string,FieldBase*>` and somehow fill the target map by deep copying the objects, but my problem is that I don't know how to determine the type of the `Field` which hides beneath each `FieldBase` pointer...

```
    // How should these be implemented ???
    Store::Store(const Store& other); 
    Store& Store::operator=(const Store& other);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Link to [cloning objects in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24939570/3747990)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the clone pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_(programming)

What you do is add a pure abstract member function to FieldBase which is defined in the most derived types (Field).

So:

```
virtual FieldBase* clone() const = 0; //! This goes in FieldBase

FieldBase* clone() const { return new Field<T>(m_value); } //! This goes in Field
```

Then in the copy constructor you iterate over the map and clone the underlying values before inserting them in the new instance's map.

Something like this:

```
Store(const Store& other)
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, FieldBase*> StoreMap;
    for (StoreMap::const_iterator it(other.m_data.begin()); it != other.m_data.end(); ++it)
        m_data.insert(std::make_pair(it->first, it->second->clone()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To implement a deep copy you can add an abstract function `virtual FieldBase * FieldBase::clone() = 0`;

The implementation `FieldBase* Field<T>::clone()` would then return `new Field<T>(*this)`;

The only thing left is to iterate over each entry of `Store::m_data` and call `it->second->clone()`;