# How to implement a copy constructor for a class with type-erased data member?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-erasure

What I am trying to achieve: I want a class to hold configuration for my program, something similar to boost::options, but boostless.
It should be used like that:

```
auto port = Config.Get<int>(Options::Port);
Config.Set<Options::Port>(12345);
```

To hold the exact values I use type erasure pattern (is it a pattern?) in `Any` class (yeah, like boost::variant/any, but boostless). So my classes look like that:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>

enum class Options {
  kListenPort = 0,
  kUdsPath,
  kConfigFile,
};

class AnyData;
class AnyDataBase;
class Any {
 public:
  template <typename T> Any(const T& any) : data_{any} {}
  Any(const Any& any) : data_{std::make_unique<AnyDataBase>(any.data_.get())} {}; // THIS IS WHERE I GOT DESPERATE
  ~Any(){}
  template <typename T> inline const T& As() const {
    if (typeid(T) != data_->type_info()){
      throw std::runtime_error("Type mismatch.");
    }else{
      return static_cast<std::unique_ptr<AnyData<T>>>(data_)->data_;
    }
  }

 private:
  struct AnyDataBase {
    virtual ~AnyDataBase(){}
    virtual const std::type_info& type_info() const = 0;
  };

  template <typename T> struct AnyData : public AnyDataBase {
    AnyData(const T& any_data) : data_{any_data} {}
    const inline std::type_info& type_info() const {
      return typeid(T);
    }
    T data_;
  };

  std::unique_ptr<AnyDataBase> data_;
};

class Option {
 private:
  Option(Any& value) : value_{value} {}
  Option() = delete; // we want the user to provide default value.
  ~Option(){};
  template <typename T> inline const T& Get() const {
    return value_.As<T>();
  }

 private:
  bool is_mandatory_;
  bool is_cmdline_;
  //TODO: add notifier
  Any value_;
};

using OptionsPair = std::pair<Options, std::shared_ptr<Option>>;
using OptionsData = std::map<Options, std::shared_ptr<Option>>;

class IConfig {
 public:
  virtual void Load(const std::string& filename) = 0;
};

class Config : public IConfig {
 public:
  Config(int argc, char** argv);
  ~Config() {};
  void Load(const std::string& filename);
  template <Options O> void Set(const Any& value);
  template <typename T> const T& Get(Options option);

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<OptionsData> data_;
  mutable std::mutex mutex_;
};
```

And when I use it like that...

```
template <Options O> void Config::Set(const Any& value) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

  if (data_->find(O) == data_->end()) {
    data_->insert(std::pair<Options, std::shared_ptr<Option>>(O, value));
    // TODO: i don't get in why it doesn't work this way:
    data_->insert(OptionsData {O, std::make_shared<Option>(value)});
  } else {
    data_->at(O) = std::make_shared<Option>(value);
  }
}
```

... I need `Any` class to have a copy constructor (I hope someone would point how I can avoid that).

And, as you can see from the comment on the copy constructor I don't know how to make it, since it is not templated. And I don't know how to create a new `unique_ptr` without knowing the type of the value, which is help in the source `unique_ptr`, I want to copy the value from.

The error is:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/memory:81:0,
                 from Config.h:5,
                 from Config.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Any::AnyDataBase; _Args = {Any::AnyDataBase*}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<Any::AnyDataBase>]’:
Config.h:23:76:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/unique_ptr.h:765:69: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Any::AnyDataBase’
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                                                     ^
In file included from Config.cpp:2:0:
Config.h:36:10: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Any::AnyDataBase’:
   struct AnyDataBase {
          ^
Config.h:38:35: note:   virtual const std::type_info& Any::AnyDataBase::type_info() const
     virtual const std::type_info& type_info() const = 0;
```

**Update:**
Just in case anybody finds this topic interesting or useful.
If i got it right one cannot simply cast a unique_ptr like that:

```
static_cast<std::unique_ptr<AnyData<T>>>(data_)->data_;
```

The most clear solution that i found so far
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21174979/2598608
Resulting code looks like that:

```
return static_unique_ptr_cast<AnyData<T>, AnyDataBase>(std::move(data_))->data_;
```

And you have to make unique_ptr member mutable or remove const qualifier from the Get() method, because the static_unique_cast<>() extracts the original deleter from the source unique_ptr, therefore modifying it.

Comment: You could/would probably need to implement a `Clone` method to get a deep copy, making it pure virtual to allow it to be implemented in the `AnyData` class (it having sufficient knowledge to full implement the copy).

Comment: Please reduce your code. That said, you declare two `AnyDataBase` classes in different scopes.

Comment: thanks, guys. Niall - not sure if i got it right - you mean implement Copy() as you say, and than use it in copy ctor? Ulrich - i'm sorry if i got you wrong, but the first one is just a forward declaration. //went to work, will respond later, cheers!

Comment: Yes, true, but it declares a different class than the one inside `Any`. If it's not necessary, you haven't finished extracting a minimal example yet. If it is necessary, you are unnecessarily confusing the reader. Since it's also in the error message, I wouldn't be surprised if it caused the error even. So, work on that, the problem will become clearer. Maybe it even goes away completely.

Comment: ah, right, my bad. will try later and update. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the `Any` class needs to know how to create a deep copy of the type erased `AnyDataBase`. It can't really to that since the `AnyDataBase` is abstract. It needs the help to the `AnyDataBase` to get that right.

One technique is to implement a "clone" method in the `AnyDataBase`. There are various signatures that this function could take, but since you are already using `std::unique`, it may be easiest to continue with its usage as follows;

```
std::unique_ptr<AnyDataBase> clone() const;
```

A sample implementation of in the `Any` class;

```
class Any {
 public:
  template <typename T> Any(const T& any) : data_{std::make_unique<AnyData<T>>(any)} {}
  Any(const Any& any) : data_{any.data_->clone()} {}; // use the clone
  ~Any(){}
  template <typename T> inline const T& As() const {
    if (typeid(T) != data_->type_info()){
      throw std::runtime_error("Type mismatch.");
    }else{
      return static_cast<std::unique_ptr<AnyData<T>>>(data_)->data_;
    }
  }
 private:
  struct AnyDataBase {
    virtual ~AnyDataBase(){}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AnyDataBase> clone() const = 0; // clone already as std::unique
    virtual const std::type_info& type_info() const = 0;
  };
  template <typename T> struct AnyData : public AnyDataBase {
    AnyData(const T& any_data) : data_{any_data} {}
    std::unique_ptr<AnyDataBase> clone() const override { return std::make_unique<AnyData<T>>(data_); }
    const inline std::type_info& type_info() const override { return typeid(T); }
    T data_;
  };
  std::unique_ptr<AnyDataBase> data_;
};
```

When attempting to copy the `Any` class, it in turn calls `clone()` on the `AnyDataBase` which then (in `AnyData`) creates a full copy of the `data_` member (of type `T`) and returns the required `std::unique`.

[Here is a sample of it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5adbd6dfae4959c).

Note: `std::unique_ptr<AnyDataBase> clone() const override { return std::make_unique<AnyData<T>>(data_); }` works as intended, the constructed `unique_ptr<AnyData<T>>` to converted to the return type `unique_ptr<AnyDataBase>` due to the [an available constructor allowing the implicit conversion of the `unique_ptr<>::pointer` types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).

---

This technique is also known as [virtual constructors](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors), and usually relies on [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type); although the covariance is not used here in the sample above. The code could easily be changed to use the covariant return over the `std::unique`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24951629/3747990) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480423/3747990) for more discussions on this.

Comment: Covariance in C++ is limited to built-in references and pointers. Smart pointers cannot be covariant. The good part is that there's no point in making it covariant here anyway.

Comment: True, in the answers linked there is some discussion over the advantages of the covariant returns over a smart pointer and vice versa. Given the code in the OP, the smart pointer is a good choice. Notes on the covariance are includes for completeness and reference; he may also choose to change the implementation he has (although I wouldn't, I favour the smart pointer here).

Comment: Great answer and very useful links, thank you. Much obliged.

Comment: @ScottTiger. Updates to the sample code have been made, the underlying principles remain unchanged.