# Need help on my C++ code on simulating a Polynomial using LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

Good day! I am making a program that simulates a Polynomial using a linked-list. So I have two classes: Term and Poly. The Term class has three private attributes and those are: int coef, int exp, and Term *next. The Poly Class has only one attribute and that is for the header node which is declared as Term *header. I tried to override the operator "=" so that I could do like this:

```
Poly p1; //creates a header note; basically this is an empty linkedlist
p1.addTerm(4, 5); //adds a term to the polynomial
Poly p2;
p2 = p1; //deletes/clears all the contents of p2 and makes a copy of all the contents of p1
```

The addTerm function works fine, so as the constructor. I guess the problem is the overriding of the "=" operator. So here is my code:

```
Poly Poly::operator =(const Poly &source) {
clearPoly();
Term *t = header;
Term *s = source.header->getNext();

while(s != NULL) {
    t->setNext(new Term(s->getCoef(), s->getExp()));
    t = t->getNext();
    s = s->getNext();   
}   

return *this;}
```

So here's my main:
[image]

Annd here is its result:
[image]

Please help me :( By the way, if something's not clear from my question, please do tell me.

**ADDITIONAL FINDINGS**
After trying to debug, I've narrowed down the problem. So here's what I found out. I tried to edit my implementation of the operator =. Here it is

```
Poly Poly::operator =(const Poly &source) {
clearPoly();
Term *t = header;
Term *s = source.header->getNext();

while(s != NULL) {
    t->setNext(new Term(s->getCoef(), s->getExp()));
    t = t->getNext();
    s = s->getNext();   
} 
display();

return *this;
}
```

The display function inside the implementation displays the desired output. However, in the main, the display function outputs unwanted/garbage values.

**RESULT OF DISPLAY FUNCTION INSIDE THE IMPLEMENTATION**
5x^6 3x^5 1x^1

**RESULT OF DISPLAY FUNCTION IN MAIN**
5574864x^5570756 5575824x^5575896 5598264x^5574864

Any idea on how that misbehaved?

Comment: wait, I'll edit my post

Comment: Please don't post code screenshots and choose a better title.

Comment: @deviantfan I'm sorry sir. I did that because pasting my code using that "Insert code" sometimes breaks the indention, therefore making it difficult to read. But noted sir! Next time, I won't be making the same mistake. But do you know the answer to my problem?

Comment: @jude I am sorry, but simply fix the indentation.  4 leading spaces signifies a code block, and are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[How to clone object in C++ ? Or Is there another solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902751/how-to-clone-object-in-c-or-is-there-another-solution) 
from what i see you want to clone an object. See if the answer here works. for some reason i can't comment, so I answered. Don't rep me if this is the right answer.