# C++ TypeId to a constructor

Tags: c++, typeid

I am trying to create a function that checks if type of object equal the type of argument, and if it does, create new object.
My class hierarchy:

`class Copier: public Action`
`class CopierX: public Copier`

So my function is:

```
void Copier::checkequality(Action b) {
    if (typeid(*this) == typeid(b))
    {
        Action b = new T x; //here at 'T' i want new type type(this)
    }
}
```

Just i think it is needed to mention - this is mentioned to be a virtual function with some 'default value', so there's another question, will it work like that:

so in this `CopierX`, `typeid(this)` will return `CopierX` type right?, then, i want to create something that will work like `Action b = new CopierX x;`

I would like to say sorry if i wrote it badly, i am fairly new to C++, i used to work a lot on simple C

Comment: Maybe you want to [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12902751/10077) objects?

Comment: You're comparing type of a pointer to the type of a class object. They will never be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this would be adding `Action* copy()` method to the Action class and implementing it within every descendant.

The other is using static polymorphism like this

```
template<typename T>
class Action {
public:
template<typename U>
void checkequality(Action<U>** b)
{
    if(std::is_same<T, U>::value) {
        *b = new T();
    }
}
};

class Copier : public Action<Copier>
{}
```